# python error message AttributeError: 'Bird' object has no attribute 'unsetflapped'

Tags: python, pygame, flappy-bird-clone

so i am learning to code games from a video coding tutorial series. And my current problem is that when i run the game I get the following error:

File "/home/dev/PycharmProjects/Game6_Flappy_Bird/modules/sprites/bird.py", line 33, in update
self.unsetflapped()
AttributeError: 'Bird' object has no attribute 'unsetflapped'

The code from the "bird class sprites file code:

```
self.is_flapped = False
    self.down_speed = 0
    self.up_speed = 9

    self.bird_idx = idx
    self.bird_idx_cycle = itertools.cycle([0,1,2,1])
    self.bird_idx_change_count = 0

def update(self, boundary_values, time_passed):

    if self.is_flapped:
        self.up_speed -= 60 * time_passed
        self.rect.top -= self.up_speed

        if self.up_speed <= 0:
            self.unsetflapped()
            self.up_speed = 9
            self.down_speed = 0
    else:
        self.down_speed += 40*time_passed
        self.rect.bottom += self.down_speed

    is_dead = False

    if self.rect.bottom > boundary_values[1]:
        is_dead = True
        self.up_speed = 0
        self.down_speed = 0
        self.rect.bottom = boundary_values[1]
    if self.rect.top < boundary_values[0]:
        is_dead = True
        self.up_speed = 0
        self.down_speed = 0
        self.rect.top = boundary_values[1]
    self.bird_idx_change_count +=1
    if self.bird_idx_change_count%5 == 0:
        self.bird_idx = next(self.bird_idx_cycle)
        self.image = list(self.images.values())[self.bird_idx]
        self.bird_idx_change_count = 0
    return is_dead

def setFlapped(self):
    if self.is_flapped:
        self.up_speed = max(12, self.up_speed+1)
    else:
        self.is_flapped = True

def unsetFlapped(self):
    self.is_flapped = False
```

I have checked this against the source code provided by the tutor and it matches exactly so I'm hoping someone can point me in the direction of what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Please note: I figured out my problem. Capitalisation of lettering. I needed to change a small "f" to a capital "F"